Redis Predixy Error: with status 4 EventError
Sometime receives Redis Predixy Error: Redis Predixy Error: with status 4 EventError, what does it mean?
Some forum said it might relate to Predixy does not have redis IP address correctly. but After I restarted predixy, I still get that error.
The configuration between Predixy and Redis are correct.
